# How should my script while using Selenium select each time next line of email from my text file to enter a Newsletter Form?

Tags: python, selenium, file, text

Hi i'm struggling at this point. Could somebody please help me! I tried already many times to solve that. Thats my first script and the task of it need to be entering emails from a text file separately into a Newsletter.

```
 from selenium import webdriver import time

 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 driver.get("https://www.zalando.pl/zalando-newsletter/")

 
 searchbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email-input"]')
 time.sleep(1)
 
 with open('EmailsNewsletter.txt') as f:
     myline = f.readline()
     while myline:
         searchbox.send_keys(myline)
         myline = f.readline()
         f.close()
 
 
 button1 =
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/label')
 time.sleep(1) button1.click()
 
 button2 =
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[8]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/button[1]')
 button2.click()
 
 button3 =
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[5]/button')
 time.sleep(1) button3.click()
 
 time.sleep(2)

 button4 =
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span')
 time.sleep(1) button4.click()
 
 time.sleep(2) driver.quit()
```

Comment: I think we need to see your `EmailsNewsletter.txt` in order to understand what's going on here. Also, can you be more specific about the problem you are encountering? Are you getting some error, or what isn't working as you expect?

Comment: maybe you should run code INSIDE for-loop

Comment: shorete `for line in f: ... code to send it ...` - without `while`, `readline()`. And DON'T use `close()` because you close file after first line. Besides you have `with ...` to close it automatically.

Comment: you should check if objects have unique ID or other valeu and then you could use shorter xpath - ie `xpath('//button[@id="..."]')`

Comment: i tried different ways to find the xpath but i couldnt find a another name for those xpaths @furas

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something many times then do it INSIDE loop (`for` or `while`).

```
with open('EmailsNewsletter.txt') as f:
    for line in f: 
        ... your code ...
```

Using `for`-loop you don't need `while` and `readline()` and code is shorter.

And don't use `close()` inside loop because this way you close file after first line and it can't read next lines. Besides if you use `with open() as f:` then you don't need `close()` because it will close automatically when you leave `with ...`

But I think you have to move all code inside loop. For every line you may have to load page again and select input.

```
from selenium import webdriver import time

# - before loop -

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# - loop -

with open('EmailsNewsletter.txt') as f:


    for line in f: 

        driver.get("https://www.zalando.pl/zalando-newsletter/")

        searchbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email-input"]')
        time.sleep(1)
        searchbox.send_keys(myline)

        button1 = ...
        time.sleep(1) 
        button1.click()
 
        button2 = ...
        time.sleep(1) 
        button2.click()
 
        button3 = ...
        time.sleep(1) 
        button3.click()
 
        button4 = ...
        time.sleep(1) 
        button4.click()

 # - after loop -

 driver.quit()
```

Comment: after one browser is finished and the second one starts, the first one doesnt close automaticly. Generally the whole script is working smoooth after your changes.

Comment: i was able to solve this problem by my own.

Comment: you have to create drive only once  - before loop. I didn't add it before but now it is in code.